# Inner join and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, inner-join

I have a problem with INNER JOIN and PDO. My query is working just fine when not using INNER JOIN. When adding INNER JOIN to the query nothing shows.

Is this a way to go or am I completely wrong?

Any suggestions?

```
public function search($searchterm)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT 
            ad.id AS idet,
            ad.lid, 
            ad.firstname AS firstnamer, 
            ad.surname AS surnamer,
            ad.socialnr AS socialnumber,
            ba.class AS classes
        FROM `everybody` ad
        INNER JOIN `students` ba
        ON idet = ba.id
        WHERE (`firstname` LIKE :search OR `surname` LIKE :search OR `classes` LIKE :search)");

    $searchterm = '%' . $searchterm . '%';
    $query->bindParam(':search', $searchterm, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['idet']. ' : '. $row['firstnamer']. ' '. $row['surnamer']. ' - '. $row['socialnumber']. ' Class: '. $row['classes']. '<br />';
    }

}
```

Comment: No results returned from an `INNER JOIN` indicates that the joined table had no rows matching the `ON` clause or all the matches were filtered away by the `WHERE` clause. If you need rows returned from the first table regardless of matches in the second, you must use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: `ON idet = ba.id` your condition doesnt match your aliases,where is `ad`? you need `ON ad.id = ba.id`

Comment: Have you enabled exceptions for PDO errors?

Comment: Hang on though - are you using emulated prepares in PDO?  The `:search` placeholder can only be used once otherwise and would cause errors at `execute()` - PDO won't permit you to reuse them.  Do you have `$this->db` configured to throw errors?  `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Also you cant reuse a parameter,you need to put `$searchterm` in 3 different variables and execute with all 3

Comment: Are you sure the join should use `id` columns from both tables? It seems a bit rare, normally I'd expect something like  students.everybody_id column, but you might have your reasons to keep it.

Comment: Solved. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in `ON` or `WHERE`. It should be

```
ON ad.id = ba.id
```

In case there are other SQL errors, you should enable PDO exceptions:

```
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing

```
INNER JOIN `students` ba
    ON ad.id = ba.id
      /*^^^^*/
WHERE (ad.firstname LIKE :search OR ad.surname LIKE :search OR ad.class LIKE :search)");
     /*^^*/                       /*^^*/                     /*^^*/
```

Comment: it should be `ad.id` instead of `ad.idet`

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your help.

Yes I have enabled exceptions for PDO errors. No error are registered. I have tried your suggestions as posted above. Nothing works.

When not using INNER JOIN, this code works like a charm:

```
public function search($searchterm)
{

    $query = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT 
            id,
            lid, 
            firstname,
            surname,
            socialnr
        FROM `everybody` 
        WHERE (`firstname` LIKE :search OR `surname` LIKE :search)");

    $searchterm = '%' . $searchterm . '%';
    $query->bindParam(':search', $searchterm, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['id']. ' : '. $row['firstname']. ' '. $row['surname']. ' - '. $row['socialnr']. '<br />';
    }

}
```

The difference between the code in my first post and this one, is the absence of INNER JOIN. I hope it will help any one to help me to understand why.

Is this the right approach? Do I need to rethink this and rewrite my function? Please advice in any direction to help me on the right track. You are most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: it might be that both tables have a firstname or surname or classes column so theres ambiguity.Try specifying the table name also